# Show that $\ker f = \ker g \implies h\circ g=f$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $f,g:V\to W$ be two linear maps. Show that $\ker f= \ker g$ iff there exists a isomorphism $h:W\to W$, such that $h\circ g=f$.

Showing "$\Leftarrow$" can be done very quickly but I haven't been able to figure out the other side so far.

I wold very much appreciate help, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: no problem, I had the idea that the question might be wrong. My suggestion is to use the fact that $f(V)\simeq V/\ker f$, so if $\ker f=\ker g\rightarrow f(V)\simeq V/\ker f\simeq V/\ker g\simeq g(V)$

Comment: You could define $h$ by that relation. You'd just have to show that it is well defined and invertible. This is pretty close to defining a map on the quotient by the kernel.

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you, that looks good, do you know if there is a particular theorem that I have to apply now in order to finish the proof?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks, that's also a good idea, I will try it right away and see how that turns out.

Comment: I would take $W$ and write it as a sum of $f(V)$ and another space $U$, so $W=f(V)\oplus U$ and use the fact that $f(V)\simeq g(V)$ imply that a space $K$ such that $g(V)\oplus K=W$ must have the same dimension of $U$, so you define $h$ on $f(V)$ as the sequence i gave you, and on $W$ take any isomorphism $W\simeq K$. You only need to prove that $h$ defined this way is an iso

Comment: @CameronWilliams The other two approaches work very well but I also find your approach to be a very good technique to know about. My proof that $h$ is well-defined didn't go well, especially showing that for $w\in W$ with $w\not\in g(V)$ the map is well-defined went very bad. Do you know how one can show well-definedness like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\ker f=\ker g$. Then, by the rank-nullity theorem, $f$ and $g$ have the same rank. Take a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ of $\ker f=\ker g$ and extend it to a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$.

Then it's not difficult to show that $\{f(v_{k+1}),\dots,f(v_n)\}$ is a basis for the image of $f$ and $\{g(v_{k+1}),\dots,g(v_n)\}$ is a basis for the image of $g$.

Extend the two sets to bases of $W$ (with the same number of vectors), say
$$
\{f(v_{k+1}),\dots,f(v_n),w_1,\dots,w_r\},\qquad
\{g(v_{k+1}),\dots,g(v_n),w'_1,\dots,w'_r\}
$$
Define $h\colon W\to W$ by
\begin{align}
&h(g(v_i))=f(v_i), && i=k+1,\dots,n\\
&h(w'_i)=w_i && i=1,\dots,r
\end{align}
Then $h$ is an isomorphism and
\begin{align}
h(g(v_i))&=f(v_i)=0 &&i=1,\dots,k \\
h(g(v_i))&=f(v_i)   &&i=k+1,\dots,n
\end{align}
so $h\circ g=f$.

If the spaces are not assumed to be finite dimensional, it's essentially the same, provided you accept existence of bases.